# How do I make a batch file that looks exactly like a command prompt?

Tags: batch, shell-script, syntax

I want to make a batch file that, when run, looks and works exactly the same as a command prompt, except that I can do something with everything the user enters (e.g. logging it). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The following short batch file will function the same as a prompt:

```
@echo off
:start
set inp=
set /P inp=%cd%^> 
:: do evil stuff with %inp% here (optional)
%inp%
goto start
```

With the following caveats: the `inp` variable will be visible to the person typing, and if you do <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it will ask you whether you want to terminate the batch file.

Walkthrough of code:

- `@` – hides the next command from the console
- `echo off` – hides all following commands from the console
- `set inp=` – sets the `inp` variable to a null string, because the following command will leave `inp` unchanged if the user just types <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- `set /P inp=` – Set /P will set a variable based on user input, with the prompt being what's after the `=` sign.
- `%cd%^>`  (note the space at the end) – The current directory, and the `>` character (for some inane reason, `^` is the escape character in Command Prompt). This is used as the prompt for the `inp` variable.
- `%inp%` – **executes** the content of **the `inp` variable**.
- `goto start` – loops back up to the top.

Obviously, you have to ask yourself why this is possible without some kind of `exec()` call or similar. The reason is that each line of batch is 'compiled' at runtime - variables are substituted into the commands. You can see this when you do a `for` loop where you use `set /A` ("arithmetic") to increment a variable each time with `%` - you get the same value every time. (For expected behavior, use `var` instead of `%var%` in set /A except for constants.)

Comment: (0) I added a line of code.  (1) What do you mean by “the `inp` variable will be visible to the person typing”?  (2) Your batch file assumes that the prompt should be `$P$G$S` (current path, greater than, and space), even if the user normally has it set to something else (and I believe that the default is `$P$G`, ***without*** the trailing space).  And if the user tries to change the prompt while talking to the batch file, there will be no effect.

Comment: (3) If the user runs another batch file, your batch file goes away.  When the new batch file terminates, the user will be back at the real Command Prompt.  (4) If the user types a multi-line command, your batch file croaks (and this is legal at the real Command Prompt).

Comment: I didn't know about #3. #1: if you do `set` which prints all variables. #0: I saw, and I think I actually had that in the second version that I don't remember. #4: I don't think I ever tried a multi-line command typed in :\. I'll look into #2 later.